# DIGImend refuses to install

Tags: drivers

I recently downloaded the .deb file for DIGImend to use with my HUION 580 graphics tablet (Not H580). I click to install, it installs before my very own eyes. But then my tablet now refuses to work.

So I restart, thinking this will solve the problem. It doesn't.
So I think maybe uninstalling DIGImend would do the trick. See, I *would* but... suddenly it just doesn't exist. I'm not sure whether this is a glitch on linux, or whether it's a glitch with the .deb file, but... yeah...

Also when I try to install DIGImend using the tar.gz file, the terminal seems to think it doesn't exist.

I've read the README file, it doesn't provide a detailed way of installation without glitches. Honestly if I can't use my tablet, I might just use my old computer and ask someone to give me their windows 7 in the interim. This is way too much stress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to uninstall the package, you can find the package name by running on of the following commands to list all recently installed packages:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ "
```

or

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log.1 | grep "\ install\ "
```

Once you know the name of the package that was installed, you can use the command `sudo apt-get purge` followed by the package name to purge whatever package was installed.

Additionally, if this is a drivers issue, you should be able to boot into an old kernel by selecting additional options from the grub menu.

From there, choose an old kernel and wait 'till the next kernel update to use a newer kernel or reinstall the current kernel after you have uninstalled the offending package of course.

---

Here is how to manually install the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
mkdir build
cd build
git clone https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers.git
cd digimend-kernel-drivers
make
sudo make install
cd
```

Run the following commands to restart the drivers:

```
sudo modprobe -r hid-kye
sudo modprobe -r hid-uclogic
sudo modprobe -r hid-huion
```

and reconnect the tablet or simply reboot the machine.

[source](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers)

You will have to reinstall whenever a new kernel is installed.

To uninstall, run the following commands:

```
cd digimend-kernel-drivers
sudo make uninstall
cd
```

Please post any errors.

---

Run these commands to reinstall the newer kernel. Also, if you see any DKMS stuff during the installation, please post.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation that took place in comments here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41935/discussion-on-answer-by-mchid-digimend-refuses-to-install) should you wish to continue it.